# simple shiny app with input text and output text

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create the most basic shiny app. Consider this simple example

```
library(stringr)

input <- 'hello my friend'

output <- mytext %>% strsplit('')
> mytext %>% strsplit('')
[[1]]
 [1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "m" "y" " " "f" "r" "i" "e" "n" "d"
```

All I need is a text box that asks for an input text form the user and then the program would show on another text box (say, just below the input box) the output of `output`.

I know how to create an input box (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/textInput.html) , but here I need to have a way to show the output of the text processing after the users enter their sentence and hit `Enter`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('input', 'Enter input'), 
  verbatimTextOutput('output')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$output <- renderText({
    req(input$input)
    strsplit(input$input, '')[[1]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: `verbatimTextOutput('output')` might be another option if you want something that more resembles console output.

Comment: amazing thanks! what is the purpose of the `req(input$input`) line?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ It runs `strsplit(input$input, '')[[1]]` line only when input is not null or not empty.

Comment: strange I am getting The application failed to start.

Comment: What happens when you copy-paste the code in the answer into the console?

Comment: actually, if I were to print a dataframe (instead of the string `h e l l o  m y  f r i e n d`) how should I modify your code? it seems `renderText` does not work in that case. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `renderTable()` in the server and `tableOutput('output')` in the ui.

Comment: thank you so much, @RonakShah. But I am getting `cannot coerce class ?"reactivevalues"? to a data.frame`

Comment: basically, instead of  `strsplit(input$input, '')[[1]]` my code call the function `myfunct(input)` which returns a dataframe. It seems the error arises as soon as I enter some text in the input box

Comment: If I do the changes (`renderTable` and `tableOutput`) and instead of `strsplit(input$input, '')[[1]]` replace it with `mtcars` it shows the dataframe after I finished typing.